# What is meant by "web" in words "world wide web"?

Tags: meaning

Dictionaries provide a description of the word depending on the specific context.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/web), [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/web)

Each word has its own meaning. And when you collect a few words in a heap, something new is formed. What is the special meaning for the "web"? Where can I find such information if dictionaries use only the word web paired with something?

I want to understand what the word "web" adds to the expression "world wide web". Does it really refer to spider webs, as suggested in comments?

If we take the phrase "[world wide web](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/world-wide-web)" separately, there is no clear understanding that the web is a metaphor to "spider web" or has some other meaning.

Comment: A spider's web is (relatively speaking) vast, complex, with many interconnections. It makes a fine metaphor for the intricate global computer system, the WWW.

Comment: Yes, the  web of WWW refers to the original spider web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **web** NOUN
> 1 A network of fine threads constructed by a spider [...]
> 2 A complex system of interconnected elements.
> [...]
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/web)

The use in "World Wide Web" is the second one.  That extended meaning already existed before "the World Wide Web" was coined in 1991.  The *Oxford English Dictionary* has an example from 1851:

> the web of roads diverging from Savannah, Charleston and Nashville.

Comment: I think the extended meaning must have come from the spiderweb meaning originally though, no?

Comment: The original meaning of "web" is *woven cloth* "OE   Prognostics (Tiber.) (2007) 319   *Tela quicumque texerit & letitiam siue tristitiam uiderit bonum nuntium significat: **webbu** swa wilc swa wyfð & blisse oððe unrotnysse gesihð god ærende g[etacnað].* - a spider's "web", i.e. a cobweb (cob = spider) is figurative/an extension of the original meaning.